# Stirling Numbers of second kind defined in terms of coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

Prove that $t^n = \sum_{k=1}^n S(n,k)t^{\underline k}$ where $t^{\underline k}$ denotes the $k$-th falling power $t(t-1)(t-2)\ldots(t-k+1)$ of$~t$.
I know that we'll have to use the recurrence relation for $S(n,k)$ here but since the summation itself involves $k$, I'm confused as how will we convert $(t-k)$ into $t^{\underline{k+1}}$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the induction proof as per the comment we use

$${n+1\brace k} = k{n\brace k} + {n\brace k-1}$$

which says that we  put $n+1$ into one of $k$ sets  of a set partition
of $n$ into  $k$ sets or we join  it as a singleton to  a partition of
$n$ into $k-1$ sets. The base case is

$$t^1 = \sum_{k=1}^1 {1\brace k} t^\underline{k} = t$$

and we see that it holds. Now suppose that

$$t^n = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} t^\underline{k}$$

which implies

$$t^{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} t\times t^\underline{k}
\\ = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} (t-k)\times t^\underline{k}
+ \sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} k \times t^\underline{k}
\\ = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} t^\underline{k+1}
+ \sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} k \times t^\underline{k}
\\ = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} {n\brace k-1} t^\underline{k}
+ \sum_{k=1}^n {n\brace k} k \times t^\underline{k}.$$

Now ${n\brace 0} = {n\brace n+1} = 0$ so this is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {n\brace k-1} t^\underline{k}
+ \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {n\brace k} k \times t^\underline{k}.$$

Apply the recurrence to get

$$t^{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {n+1\brace k} t^\underline{k}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, our teacher won't cover generating functions. He proved it just using induction, basic combinatorics and little algebra as:-
t^(n+1)= t*t^n=[(t-k)+k]*t^n.
Then using induction, he used t^n = (Sum over k=1 to n) [S(n,k)*(t falling k)].
And then S(n+1,k) = k*S(n,k)+S(n,k-1) in the above result somehow popped up as the coefficient of t^k. I was unable to understand this "gap" between the above mentioned steps. Please help me a bit in this. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped